# How to find all elements in A but not B in lodash?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

In Javascript, I am trying to do the following:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5];
B = [3,4,6];
C = ??? // Do something here
console.log(c); // Should be [1,2,5]
```

I'd think this is common enough to be done easily in lodash, but I can't find any function that will do it.  The best I can come up with is:

```
C=_.intersection(A,_.xor(A,B));
```

Is there a single function that I'm missing to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Lodash v4.17.15:

You could simply just do, `var C = _.pullAll(A, B);`

```js
var A = [1,2,3,4,5];
var B = [3,4,6];
var C = _.pullAll(A, B);
console.log(C); // Should be [1,2,5]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

For v3.10.1:

You could simply just do, `var C = _.difference(A, B);`

```js
var A = [1,2,3,4,5];
var B = [3,4,6];
var C = _.difference(A, B);
console.log(C); // Should be [1,2,5]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@3.10.1/index.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: It looks like that's new in v4.  Is there a v3 equivalent?  I'd rather not go through the pain of an upgrade if I can help it.

Comment: @StackTracer I added v3 equivalent with working snippet :)

Comment: I would actually remove the `pullAll` option as it mutates A - which is not desirable and does not reflect the answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like `A.filter(item => !B.includes(item));` even without lodash?

Comment: well, most of the motivation for wanting a lodash solution is that it could be chained into an existing operation, but this answer easily translates.

Comment: The main purpose of using lodash one liners is to have better readability in the code.